# What is a good way to stop a looping animation when moving?

Tags: unity

I have a looping attack animation, is there an easy way to stop this animation when my character starts moving? Atm I have to always call my "stop" trigger and it doesnt always work great and feels messy.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking maybe for https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html?

Comment: @Zibelas the Locomotion node in my screenshot is a blend tree. I am looking for an easy way to make sure I break out of the "Attack" node which is on loop, when my character starts moving.